# Why does my custom UIAlertViewDelegate crash the debugger?

Tags: iphone, debugging, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, uialertview

The delegate is as follows:

```
public class DoneAlertViewDelegate : UIAlertViewDelegate
{
    UINavigationController controller;
    EKEventStore store;
    EKEvent ekEvent;
    public DoneAlertViewDelegate(UINavigationController controller, EKEventStore storeEvent, EKEvent userEvent)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
        store = storeEvent;
        ekEvent = userEvent;

    }
    public override void Clicked (UIAlertView alertview, int buttonIndex)
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            var alert = new UIAlertView("Date Stored", "Date saved in calendar",null,"OK",null);
            alert.Show();
            SaveEvent();
            controller.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
        }
        else if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            controller.PopToRootViewController(true);
        }

    }

    public override void Canceled (UIAlertView alertView)
    {

    }

    public void SaveEvent()
    {
        var err = new NSError();
        store.SaveEvent(ekEvent,EKSpan.ThisEvent,out err);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when I'm debugging, this always crashes the debugger (SIGSEGV) error is called.  However, when I simply run the program, it executes as planned.  Is this a known issue with monotouch (I'm getting an Objective-C exception) or am I just missing some crucial code to make this work?  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  Application Output -

Monotouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown "Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: - [UITouchData alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdc614e0

Comment: You should probably post your console logs.

Answer (score 4):

The UIAlertView is probably getting collected. Try making it a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turns out the AlertView DELEGATE was somehow going out of scope. I added it to a temporary variable in my AppDelegate (only as a temporary hack) and it worked. I  imagine setting it as a class variable as Mike suggested (but setting the Delegate, not the UIAlertView) should fix it.